# EDGE browser unable to render report - where as its working with IE and Chrome

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportserver, ssrs-2017

I was referring this to configure report service : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5237/installing-sql-server-reporting-services-2017/

Regarding current report server credential,here is what I have done (along with other required steps):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now my question is: What credential I should use to access this from the browser? If you refer credential attached credential screen, its showing nothing. May be I'm not getting which username and password I should use. I have separate credential for SQL server login.

Should I use my Windows credential? Or SQL Server Credential? Or any other? 
**Moreover, is IIS installation is mandatory** ?? Please suggest.

I have Configured a new credential for report server like below:
[image]

However, I'm still getting error:
[image]

When Im setting an execution account, its showing error: below screen:
[image]
The more detailed description is below:

The username or password is not valid or you do not have permission to access this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient.RSClientConnection.CreateConnection()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient.RSConnectionInfo.GetRSConnectionObject(Boolean ensureOpenConnection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient.RSConnectionInfo.RSTypeImpl.ProceedWithConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.RSType.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.IServerType.ProceedWithConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

**With Chrome and IE11 its running via "BUILTIN\Administrators"?** That is,When I'm trying to access the same report URL from chrome and IE, its working. However, when I'm seeing ""Site Setting" its showing me "BUILTIN\Administrators". Really getting confused, whats going on?

Note: I have configured execution account as well. Even after providing execution account credential, its not working. I think, Microsoft has to fix the issue. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-the-unattended-execution-account-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017

Browser is asking me the credential (tried with different credential) and after providing the credential its showing nothing. No error message. Any one faced such issues? How to resolve this?

Comment: Does anything show in the Dev Console if you "Inspect Element"?

Comment: (Dev Console = Press F12)

Comment: Strange thing is its asking me credential again and again. And, nothing showing when I press F12. Its blank.

Comment: Could you try in private mode of Edge browser ?

Comment: Modified my question. Any suggestion please?